# extra sql query column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select extra columns from another table in my sql query.

```
SELECT      
    d.UnitID,
    b.BookingID,
    d.ProjectID,
    b.ClientName,
    (SELECT LetterTypeID 
     FROM Letters 
     WHERE ProjectID = 27 AND BookingID = b.BookingID)                  
FROM        
    ScheduledDues AS d 
INNER JOIN
    Booking AS b ON d.BookingID = b.BookingID 
INNER JOIN
    Units AS u ON d.UnitID = u.UnitID               
WHERE
    d.ProjectID = 27 
    AND DueFrom <= GETDATE()
GROUP BY    
    d.BookingID, d.UnitID, d.ProjectID,
    u.UnitNo, b.ClientName
HAVING      
    SUM(DueTill) = 0
```

How can I do this? and have it in group by. Is selecting `LetterTypeID` possible?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Above inline query in select should work if it is returning 1 row for matching condition and not disturbing the granularity of data.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use LetterTypeID in group by like below or You can fetch results without letters table into temp and join it with letters to get LetterTypeID

```
SELECT       d.UnitID,
            b.BookingID,
            d.ProjectID,
            b.ClientName,
            l.LetterTypeID                   
FROM        ScheduledDues AS d INNER JOIN
            Booking AS b ON d.BookingID = b.BookingID INNER JOIN
            Units AS u ON d.UnitID = u.UnitID INNER JOIN
            Letters AS l ON b.BookingID=l.BookingID AND l.ProjectID=27          
WHERE       d.ProjectID = 27 AND
            DueFrom <= GETDATE()

GROUP BY    d.BookingID,
            d.UnitID,
            d.ProjectID,
            u.UnitNo,
            b.ClientName,
            l.LetterTypeID
HAVING      SUM(DueTill) = 0
```

Comment: i don't want to use join. i am using above query for audit purpose

Comment: try using temp table

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this query

```
SELECT  BookingID, UnitID, ProjectID
    UnitNo, ClientName ,LetterTypeID FROM (SELECT      
    d.UnitID,
    b.BookingID,
    d.ProjectID,
    b.ClientName,
    DueTill,
    (SELECT LetterTypeID 
     FROM Letters 
     WHERE ProjectID = 27 AND BookingID = b.BookingID)   LetterTypeID               
FROM        
    ScheduledDues AS d 
INNER JOIN
    Booking AS b ON d.BookingID = b.BookingID 
INNER JOIN
    Units AS u ON d.UnitID = u.UnitID               
WHERE
    d.ProjectID = 27 
    AND DueFrom <= GETDATE()) x
GROUP BY    
    BookingID, UnitID, ProjectID,
    UnitNo, ClientName ,LetterTypeID
HAVING      
    SUM(DueTill) = 0
```